# Writing code in recent expl3 while keeping compatibility with older systems

Tags: expl3, backward-compatibility

I would like to write some expl3 code using recent additions to the system (typically `\seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn` which the docs say was introduced in 2018) but since this would potentially be used on older installs of LaTeX which I have no control on (I set myself the goal of having the thing work on TeXlive 2014, which is the oldest available on overleaf), I need to preserve compatibility and am wondering how to best go about it.

At the moment my plan is to have an include file full of entries like

```
\cs_if_exist:NF \wh_at_ever { \cs_new:Npn \wh_at_ever #1 { ... } }
```

where the contents are taken from a recent version of `expl3-code.tex`, adding missing functions as I go, but it feels both brutal and potentially risky in case some internal code has changed in between.

Another option would be to copy or reimplement the functions that I need under a private namespace and use that, but I would really prefer for the actual code to use the official expl3 functions, if only for documentation purposes.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I wouldn't try to support old systems unless you get very well paid for it. It is quite time consuming to write such codes, you need test systems for all sort of variants and  can easily get hard to debug errors. And all this probably for a quite small number of users.

Comment: I totally agree with you on the principle (and I am not getting paid at all for it), but I am afraid of what system would be available in typical math departments, e.g. texlive coming with ubuntu 18.04 LTS, which I would expect to be installed everywhere, is from 2017 ...